# Does MongoDB Limit() load all the documents in memory?

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$result = $collection->find('some constraints')->limit(10);
```

Now suppose the documents satisfying "some constraints" are 10000.

So, does this query first fetch 10000 documents in memory and returns 10 to me or does it load only 10 documents specified by `limit`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently written an [article](http://derickrethans.nl/cursors-in-mongodb.html) about this. In short, when you use limit, the driver will request only 10 items from the server so on the client side, not more than 10 documents will be in memory. "limit" is strictly a *client* thing, and is only used while fetching the documents. The query will still run in full.

On the server side, all documents that match your find() constraint are going to be read which means the OS will put those into memory from disk, if they are not in memory yet. But then again, from the the MongoDB server process, all documents are always in memory anyways; it's up the operating system to do the caching of this, and paging to and from disk. Read more about how MongoDB manages memory at [their docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching).

Comment: Depending on your query MongoDB may not look for all documents matching your query, but should stop as soon as it found the given number. At least I expect this behavior as it would be highly inperformant to behave differently. But as soon as you've some sort in your query, MongoDB has to lookup all entries as it can't sort without knowing all documents at first.   Indeed as MongoDB holds everything in memory this doesn't make much difference as long as your dataset is smaller than your memory.

Comment: @Derick :Thanks. I am clear with this. But doesn't this affect performance? For eg, say I have millions of documents, so just to grab 10 documents whole collection will have to be read on server side.

Comment: @Derick: I have explained our issue in detail here. Please provide your suggestions. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10879709/1265884